# jQuery .attr retrieving custom attribute returns undefined

Tags: jquery, attr

i have the following problem using jquery.

I have sth like this

```
<div id="yxz" value="1">
  <span class="delete"></span>
</div>
```

now I have this fn but it only returns "undefined", it does however return the id, or class if I ask for this.

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
  alert($(this).parent("div").attr("value"));
});
```

I used to get this value with the same attr stuff. Does this have sth to do with me using the jquery 1.6.1 now instead of 1.5.2.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To retrieve the value of elements, use [val()](http://docs.jquery.com/Val). Since divs don't have values, you should use [data()](http://docs.jquery.com/Data) to set and get data.

Comment: Well, I did not really use data() since my values come from the db and are already there, but using data="1" instead of value="1" and than .attr("data") did work. With jquery 1.5 the value thing worked as well.

Comment: @Lukas: I think he meant for you to use `data-value="1"` and then `.data('value')`

Comment: actually, the data function doesn't set any attributes to the element. It's just an internal map, that stores data to a given element. However, "value" is an kind of an reserved thing and should be avoided in such situations. Glad you got it done.

Comment: I just figured this out myself too, but thanks anyway. I am using it like you suggested now. :)

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm this code snippet works perfectly in Chrome 11, Firefox 4 and IE 9 using the jQuery Git version.

EDIT: For the ones advising prop(), check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). Prop() is used for boolean attributes like: checked, disabled etc.

Answer (score 0):

if using the latest jQuery, try with:

[`$.prop(propertyName);`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since jQuery 1.6 I think you need to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work fine in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kV34y/), using jQuery 1.6