# Creating a new attribute with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, attr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery .attr retrieving custom attribute returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303775/jquery-attr-retrieving-custom-attribute-returns-undefined)

I've got a weird problem, but I'm hoping I'm just doing something stupid.  I'm trying to create a new attribute on an `<img>` element using jQuery, and this line:

```
$(selector).attr('selected', 'no');
```

When I inspect the DOM in Chrome, I just see selected="selected", no matter what I set the value to.

Just some extra info:  I can't use just boolean values, as I need to keep track of "Yes", "No" and "Partial" property values.  I'm calling a JS function from the "onClick" event of the img itself, and passing `this` as a parameter.  I've inspected the object in the method, and the right object is passed; the fact that the attribute is set (even if to the wrong value) also supports this.

I'm dead certain I'm doing something stupid here...  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Selected is already an attribute in the HTML standard, so you cannot create a custom attribute with the same name. In that case, you should use the `data-` attributes instead and create an attribute `data-selected` for instance.

In jQuery you handle the custom data attributes using the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method.

The custom data attributes are described in the HTML5 spec [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes).

Answer (score 5):

you could insert a `data-*` custom attribute like so

```
$(selector).data('selected', 'no');
```

your element will set a `data-selected` attribute

Answer (score 2):

If you need to attach arbitrary data to an element, use `.data()`, not `.attr()`.

Answer (score 1):

A DOM property is different than a DOM attribute ;)

I'd suggest using `$(selector).data()` for your use case.